# Add condition to "where" clause in Prisma

Tags: javascript, sql, database, prisma

I have the following filters in a Prisma query and I need to append a `start_date: { equals: null }` in addition to the existing `start_date: { lt: today }`, something like `WHERE (id_1, id_2, id_3) IN ([array]) AND (start_date < today OR start_date IS NULL)` but I can't find a working solution.

```html
where: {
  OR: ids.map((id) => ({
    id_1: id.1,
    id_2: id.2,
    id_3: id.3,
  })),
  start_date: { lt: today },
},
```

This options doesn't work:

- start_date: { OR: [{ lt: today }, { equals: null }] }
- start_date: [{ lt: today }, { equals: null }]
- AND: [{ start_date: { lt: today } }, { start_date: { equals: null } }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can only have one OR in an object, combine two filter objects with AND:

```js
{ AND: [{ OR: /* ... */ }, { OR: [{ start_date: null }, { start_date: /*...*/ }] }] }
```